# Публичные и частные пространства адресов

Tags: сеть, ip-address

> Публичные "белые" адреса используются в сети Интернет. Публичным
>   IP-адресом называется IP-адрес, который используется для выхода в
>   Интернет. Доступ к устройству с публичным IP-адресом можно получить из
>   любой точки глобальной сети, т.к. публичные (глобальные) IP-адреса
>   маршрутизируются в Интернете, в отличие от частных (серых) IP-адресов.
>   Однако, в связи с тем что "белых" адресов существует ограниченное
>   количество, в локальных сетях используются частные (серые) IP-адреса.
>   Они не маршрутизируются в Интернете и на них нельзя отправить трафик
>   из Интернета, только из конкретной частной локальной сети. Для
>   домашних пользователей провайдер может предоставлять один или
>   несколько публичных IP-адресов (как правило, это платная услуга).
>   Маршрутизатор позволяет компьютерам локальной сети (с частными
>   IP-адресами) использовать для выхода в Интернет публичный IP-адрес,
>   установленный на внешнем интерфейсе (WAN) устройства. Именно этот
>   внешний IP-адрес может быть использован для до-ступа из Интернета в
>   локальную сеть. Частные IP:
>
> 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255 (префикс 10/8)
>   172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 (префикс 172.16/12)
>   192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255 (префикс 192.168/16)

А что с адресами не входящими в диапазон частных ip?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Что вы хотите знать про эти адреса

Comment: Откуда цитата-то? явно "водку клюшница варила"...

Comment: @Mike сам вопрос это "Публичные и частные пространства адресов", точнее рассказать о них. У меня в ответах написано то, что в цитате. Не исключаю, что сам ответ в корне не верный, тогда какой правильный ?

Comment: Ну написано вроде правильно, грубых ошибок не видно. что еще требуется. Эссе на 10 страниц, тут никто писать не будет

Comment: @Mike мне эссе не надо, как и таких комментариев. Меня просто интересует, что за данными диапазонами вот и все. Можно в общих чертах.

Comment: все равно не понимаю. в этих диапазонах локальные адреса, все что вне этих диапазонов - публичные, т.е. свободно маршрутизируемые в интернете. и про те и про другие в вашей выдержке написано, что они такое